# How do I use a databound identifier in databound control to get the specific resource in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, data-binding, resourcedictionary

I have databound button whose content (text) is supposed to be retrieved from a merged dictionary in the applications resources.

**But I can't hard code the resource's key because I don't know the key. The key needs to somehow be retrieved from the databound item.**

Usually one would just bind the button's text to a property like so:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Path=DisplayName}" ... />
```

But I need the button's text to be fetched from a resource instead, while the button is still databound like before:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <s:String x:Key="EnglishButtonText">Enter</s:String>  
</Application.Resources>
```

And the bound dataitem would contain a property `public string Name{get;set;}` whose value is `'EnglishButtonText'`.

So something like this:

```
<Button Content="{DynamicResource{Binding Path=Name}}" ... />
```

Can this be done?

Comment: Everything can be done. I would probably describe the exact reasons you need this and why are you trying to solve things like you are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved with [**IValueConverter**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx) in place which will return resource value.

*Converter*:

```
public class ResourceLoopkupConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                          CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return App.Current.Resources[value];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return Binding.DoNothing;
    }
}
```

*XAML*:

```
<Button Content="{Binding Name,
                  Converter={StaticResource ResourceLoopkupConverter}}"/>
```

Of course you have to declare instance of converter in XAML to use it.

Comment: Thank you. So the converter would receive the bound value from the Name property? I will try this.

Comment: Yeah `Name` should have the resource key.

Comment: since the code is accessing the resource via index, what happens when the resource value changes. I wanted this to behave like a dynamic resource. Can I somehow get a reference to the button inside the converter, and call its 'SetResourceReference' method?

Comment: Indexer is used to access resource by its resource name. Whenever resource name gets changed, converter will get fired and apply the resource automatically.